# UnicodeDecodeError from app.py after input from HTML

Tags: python, html, sql, postgresql

I am currently building an application with python and the module flask. I've created an input form in my HTML file and when I write something that doesn't contain "åäö", it works. It will communicate with my PSQL. But if I write something that contains "åäö", it will say:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
```

in my app.py file. I think there is a problem with my PSQL table but I don't know.

What's the problem?

I appreciate all help that I get.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have a small flask application with a register form, and that kind of input gives me no problem. I'm only using a DataRequired() validator on the field.
The data is then inserted in a SQLite DB, which has an UTF-8 encoding.

I think maybe you should check your DB encoding and then decide if you'll change it or you'll just change string encoding (when possible) from python in order to be able to insert into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an encoding discrepancy between the server and client. For instance, if your app supports UTF-8, use UTF-8 in the database as well.

Using the psycopg2 module might be helpful.

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extensions
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
```